# Spring boot загрузка файлов размером больше 15 мб

Tags: java, spring

Spring Boot 1.4.3. При загрузке файлов более 15МБ выскакивает HTTP 405 и даже Exception не кидает...Mysql max_allowed_packet=100mb;

```
  spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
  spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=50MB

@PostMapping("addPost/{name}&{post}&{title}")
public String addPost(@PathVariable String name,
        @PathVariable TypePost post,@PathVariable  String title,
        @RequestParam  String contractor,@RequestParam  String note,
        @RequestParam ("files")  List<MultipartFile>files){
       log.info("\n\nPOST: /admin/addPost/"+name+" "+post+"   

     "+title+'&'+contractor+'&'+note);
     Message message = new Message(false);

    DocumentType type = service.getDocumentType(post, title);
    if(type==null){
        List<TypePost>types = new ArrayList<>();
        if(post==TypePost.INPUT||post==TypePost.OUTPUT){
            types.add(TypePost.INPUT);
            types.add(TypePost.OUTPUT);
        }else {
            types.add(TypePost.CORPORATION);
        }
        type = new DocumentType(title);
        type.setTypes(types);
        service.addDocumentType(type);
    }

    Document document =  new Document(type);
    service.addDocument(document);

    if (!multipartToFileConverter(files, document)) {
        message.setText("Сталася помилка. Повторіть, будь ласка, спробу!");
        log.info("\n\nReturn: "+gson.toJson(message));
        return gson.toJson(message);
    }

    document.setNote(note);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Hello!");

    Project project = service.getProject(name);
    long curDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime();
    System.out.println("Hello!");

    try{
        if(post.equals(TypePost.CORPORATION)){
            long postSize = service.getCorporationPostList(project).size()+1;
            CorporationPost  cPost = new CorporationPost(postSize, TypePost.CORPORATION, curDate);
            System.out.println("Hello!");
            cPost.setProject(project);
            System.out.println("Hello!");
            cPost.setDocument(document);
            System.out.println("Hello!");
            service.addCorporationPost(cPost);
            System.out.println("Hello!");
        }else if(post.equals(TypePost.INPUT)){
            long postSize = service.getInputPostList(project).size()+1;
            InputPost iPost = new InputPost(postSize,  

           TypePost.INPUT,curDate, document, project);

            Contractor contractor2 = service.getContractor(contractor);
            if(contractor2==null){
                contractor2 = new Contractor(contractor);
                service.addContractor(contractor2);
                iPost.setContractor(contractor2);
            }else{
                iPost.setContractor(contractor2);
            }

            service.addInputPost(iPost);
        }else{
            long postSize = service.getOutputPostList(project).size()+1;
            OutputPost oPost = new OutputPost(postSize, 

           TypePost.OUTPUT,curDate, document, project);

            Contractor contractor2 = service.getContractor(contractor);
            if(contractor2==null){
                oPost.setContractor(new Contractor(contractor));
            }else{
                oPost.setContractor(contractor2);
            }

            service.addOutputPost(oPost);
        }

        message = new Message(true,"Кореспонденцію успішно додано.");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn(e.getMessage());
        message.setText("Сталася помилка. Повторіть, будь ласка, спробу!");
    }

    log.info("\n\nReturn: "+gson.toJson(message));
    return gson.toJson(message);
}

private boolean multipartToFileConverter(List<MultipartFile>mFiles,Document  

   document) throws RuntimeException {
    List<File>files = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            for(int i=0;i<mFiles.size();i++){
                File file = new File();
                file.setPageNumber(i+1);
                file.setData(mFiles.get(i).getBytes());
                file.setType(mFiles.get(i).getContentType());
                file.setDocument(document);
                service.addFile(file);
                files.add(file);
                document.getFiles().add(file);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("\n\n"+e.getMessage()+"\n\n");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="documents")
public class Document implements Serializable{
@Id
@Expose
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
@Expose
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String note;
@Expose
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
private DocumentType type;
@Expose
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "document")
private List<File>files = new ArrayList<>();
@Expose(serialize=false)
@OneToOne(mappedBy="document")
private Post post;

public Document() {}

}

@Entity
@Table(name="files")
public class File implements Serializable{
@Id
@Expose
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
@Expose
private int pageNumber;
@Expose(serialize = false)
@Column(columnDefinition="LONGBLOB")
private byte[]data;
@Expose
private String type;
@ManyToOne
@Expose(serialize=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "document_id")
private Document document;

public File() {}
}
```

Comment: какой тип данных у поля в БД для файлов?

Comment: @MrFylypenko LONGBLOB

Comment: @MrFylypenko я исправил там....Не 404, а 405 ошибка

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос конфигурацию проекта, и описание ошибки при 405, ну и версию спринга тоже.

Comment: @MrFylypenko описание ошибки нет...

Comment: Только что попробовал скачать [официальный пример](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files/tree/master/complete) , у меня все заработало для файлов  больше 20 мб. При превышении моего лимита возникает 500 ошибка на размер файла. Скорее всего эта ошибка возникает из-за названия файла, попробуйте указать его на латинице без пробелов. Так же возможно в запросе с файлом передаются неправильные дополнительные параметры.

Comment: @MrFylypenko у меня загрузился файл 25мб, а больше не могу. С названием все нормально...Файлы же меньшего размера нормально грузятся

Comment: Без более подробного описания как работает Ваш проект невозможно установить в чем проблема. Причин может быть много, банально нет места на сервере, форма отправки добавляет лишний параметр, либо сервер его требует. Добавьте данные как отправляете и как принимаете файл на сервере.

Comment: @MrFylypenko добавил...

Comment: Еще добавьте информацию из консоли браузера, из вкладки сеть, при вознокновении ошибки.

Comment: @MrFylypenko Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()

Comment: @MrFylypenko странная штука, когда сумарный размер данных в базе данных достигает 100мб - из нее перестает доставаться данные.